# Embla-carousel-react slow image loading

Tags: reactjs, next.js, embla-carousel

I am currently working on image carousel and there is some issue with image loading. My stack is: Next.js + embla. When I am trying to scroll carousel first 2 images loads pretty fast, but third is very slow for loading. Here is my code:

```
/* eslint-disable jsx-a11y/control-has-associated-label */
import React, {
  ReactElement,
  useCallback,
  useEffect,
  useState,
  MouseEventHandler,
} from 'react';
import { CarouselProps } from 'interfaces/components';
import Image from 'next/image';
import useEmblaCarousel from 'embla-carousel-react';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import styles from './carousel.module.scss';

const Carousel = (props: CarouselProps): ReactElement => {
  const { images, hasShadow } = props;

  const [emblaRef, embla] = useEmblaCarousel({ loop: true });
  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(0);

  const scrollPrev = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (embla) embla.scrollPrev();
    },
    [embla]
  );

  const scrollNext = useCallback(
    (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (embla) embla.scrollNext();
    },
    [embla]
  );

  const scrollTo = useCallback(
    (e, index) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (embla) embla.scrollTo(index);
    },
    [embla]
  );

  const onSelect = useCallback(() => {
    if (!embla) return;
    setSelectedIndex(embla.selectedScrollSnap());
  }, [embla, setSelectedIndex]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!embla) return;
    onSelect();
    embla.on('select', onSelect);
  }, [embla, onSelect]);

  const imagesOrPlaceholder =
    images == null || images.length === 0
      ? ['/images/placeholder.jpg']
      : images;

  const NextButton = ({ onClick }: { onClick: MouseEventHandler }) => (
    <button
      className={[styles.arrow, styles.next].join(' ')}
      onClick={onClick}
      type="button"
    >
      <svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        height="48px"
        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        width="48px"
        fill="#FFFFFF"
      >
        <path d="M9.29 15.88L13.17 12 9.29 8.12c-.39-.39-.39-1.02 0-1.41.39-.39 1.02-.39 1.41 0l4.59 4.59c.39.39.39 1.02 0 1.41L10.7 17.3c-.39.39-1.02.39-1.41 0-.38-.39-.39-1.03 0-1.42z" />
      </svg>
    </button>
  );

  const PrevButton = ({ onClick }: { onClick: MouseEventHandler }) => (
    <button
      className={[styles.arrow, styles.prev].join(' ')}
      onClick={onClick}
      type="button"
    >
      <svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        height="48px"
        viewBox="0 0 24 24"
        width="48px"
        fill="#FFFFFF"
      >
        <path d="M14.71 15.88L10.83 12l3.88-3.88c.39-.39.39-1.02 0-1.41-.39-.39-1.02-.39-1.41 0L8.71 11.3c-.39.39-.39 1.02 0 1.41l4.59 4.59c.39.39 1.02.39 1.41 0 .38-.39.39-1.03 0-1.42z" />
      </svg>
    </button>
  );

  return (
    <div className={styles.embla} style={{ boxShadow: `${hasShadow ? "0px 4px 4px #AEA6A5" : ''}` }}>
      <div className={styles.embla__viewport} ref={emblaRef}>
        <div className={styles.embla__container}>
          {imagesOrPlaceholder.map((img, idx) => (
            <div className={styles.embla__slide} key={img}>
              <div className={styles.embla__slide__inner}>
                <Image
                  src={img}
                  layout="responsive"
                  width="100%"
                  height="125%"
                  objectFit="cover"
                  quality={100}
                  className={styles.featuredTileImage}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
      {imagesOrPlaceholder.length > 1 && (
        <>
          <PrevButton onClick={scrollPrev} />
          <NextButton onClick={scrollNext} />
        </>
      )}
      <div className={styles.dots}>
        {imagesOrPlaceholder.length > 1 && imagesOrPlaceholder.map((_value, index) => (
          <div className={styles.dotContainer} key={index}>
            <div className={styles.dotAspect} />
            <div
              role="button"
              onClick={(e) => scrollTo(e, index)}
              onKeyDown={(e) => scrollTo(e, index)}
              tabIndex={0}
              className={clsx(
                styles.dot,
                selectedIndex === index && styles.active
              )}
            />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Carousel;
```

And this is my carousel

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwaBB.png

Maybe this is some issue with Image component from Next.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was about Image component lazy-loading, which is fixed by installing sharp package or as a radical measure set preolading for Image